# Do odd numbers $n$ satisfying $\gcd(n, \sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$ have a special form?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of divisors of the positive integer $n$.

Using Sage Cell Server, I was able to get the following odd numbers $n < 5000$ satisfying $\gcd(n, \sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$:

$$117 = {{3}^2}\cdot{13}$$
$$135 = {{3}^3}\cdot{5}$$
$$585 = {{3}^2}\cdot{5}\cdot{13}$$
$$775 = {{5}^2}\cdot{31}$$
$$819 = {{3}^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}$$
$$891 = {{3}^4}\cdot{11}$$
$$1287 = {{3}^2}\cdot{11}\cdot{13}$$
$$1305 = {{3}^2}\cdot{5}\cdot{29}$$
$$1485 = {{3}^3}\cdot{5}\cdot{11}$$
$$1989 = {{3}^2}\cdot{13}\cdot{17}$$
$$2295 = {{3}^3}\cdot{5}\cdot{17}$$
$$2793 = {3}\cdot{{7}^2}\cdot{19}$$
$$3515 = {5}\cdot{19}\cdot{37}$$
$$4095 = {{3}^2}\cdot{5}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}$$
$$4455 = {{3}^4}\cdot{5}\cdot{11}$$
$$4655 = {5}\cdot{{7}^2}\cdot{19}$$

<s>Is this surprising?  Or is there an underlying explanation for this phenomenon?</s>

**Updated Question (Added October 30, 2018)**

> Under what suitable conditions does it follow that $3 \mid n$, if $n$ is an odd number satisfying $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$?

**Note that it follows from the inequality $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$ that $n$ must be composite.**

Comment: what phenomenon?

Comment: That the odd numbers satisfying the inequality are mostly divisible by $3^2$, save for a few exceptions.

Comment: @fleablood I think sigma is the sum of the divisors

Comment: @JorgeFernández You are right, I've misread the question, I thought the $\sigma$ is $\varphi$.

Comment: can you please say how strong of a result you are looking for? I think it is easy to prove there are infinitely many $n$ that are not multiples of $9$ but I dont know if we can say anything about the asymptotic density of those $n$

Comment: @JorgeFernández, something along the lines of Acccumulation's answer would be just right, except that I would like a proof using Analytic Number Theory, perhaps using ideas in the paper [On the greatest common divisor of a number and its sum of divisors](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1301586311).

Comment: I noticed that, in my list of odd numbers less than $5000$ satisfying $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$, if $3^2 || n$, then $13 || n$.  It seems to be telling me that, if $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$, then $\sigma(n)/n = a/b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ (satisfying $\gcd(a,b)=1$? I am not too sure).  It would also, perhaps, be fruitful to investigate the solitary/friendly status of odd composite numbers $n$ satisfying $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: (1) One can prove that there is an odd $n$ such that $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))\gt\sqrt n,3^2\mid n$ and $13\color{red}{\not\mid} n$. (2) I don't understand your comment "It seems to be telling ..." Isn't $\sigma(n)/n$ always a rational number? Can you make it clearer?

Comment: @mathlove, I would be delighted to hear about your counterexample.  Note that I want $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}, 3^2 || n$, and $13 || n$, where $u^t || v$ means that $u^t | v$ and $u^{t+1} \nmid v$.  (That is, $u^t || v$ means that $u^t$ is the highest power of $u$ that exactly divides $v$.)

Comment: I've added a counterexample. Can you respond to (2) in my previous comment?

Comment: @mathlove, yes the abundancy index of $n$ is always a rational number. I was thinking along the lines that, $n$ and $\sigma(n)$ are related by an equation, so that knowledge of prime factors of $n$ lead to knowledge of prime factors of $\sigma(n)$, via a method known as sigma chaining or otherwise known as the factor chain approach.

Comment: I don't know if you are interested in this, but one can prove that there are infinitely many odd integers $n$ such that $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))\gt\sqrt n$ and $3\not\mid n$.

Comment: @mathlove: I would be more than pleased to see a proof of the assertion in your last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim** : There are infinitely many odd numbers $n$ such that
$$3\not\mid n\ \ \qquad\text{and}\ \ \qquad \gcd(n,\sigma(n))\gt\sqrt n$$

*Proof* :

For $$n=p^{2a}\sigma(p^{2a})$$ where $p$ is a prime larger than $3$ and $a$ is a positive integer such that $(p,a)\not\equiv (1,1)\pmod 3$, we have
$$2\not\mid n,\qquad\qquad 3\not\mid n$$
and
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n))=\gcd(p^{2a}\sigma(p^{2a}),\sigma(p^{2a})\sigma(\sigma(p^{2a})))\ge \sigma(p^{2a})\gt \sqrt{p^{2a}\sigma(p^{2a})}=\sqrt n\ .\quad\blacksquare$$

---

Some small examples :

- $n=5^{2}\sigma(5^{2})=5^2\cdot 31$ which you've already shown.
- $n=5^{4}\sigma(5^{4})=5^4\cdot 11\cdot 71$
- $n=5^{6}\sigma(5^{6})=5^6\cdot 19531$
- $n=7^4\sigma(7^4)=7^4\cdot 2801$
- $n=7^6\sigma(7^6)=7^6\cdot 29\cdot 4733$
- $n=7^{10}\sigma(7^{10})=7^{10}\cdot 1123\cdot 293459$
- $n=11^2\sigma(11^2)=7\cdot 11^2\cdot 19$
- $n=11^4\sigma(11^4)=5\cdot 11^4\cdot 3221$
- $n=11^6\sigma(11^6)=11^6\cdot 43\cdot 45319$

---

**Added** :

For $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$, we have
$$\sigma(p^{2a})=1+p+\cdots +p^{2a}\equiv 1+1+\cdots +1\equiv 2a+1\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$$
for $a\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

For $p\equiv -1\pmod 3$, we have
$$\sigma(p^{2a})=1+p+\cdots +p^{2a}=1-1+1-1+1-\cdots -1+1\equiv 1\pmod 3$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Gladly accepting this now =)

Comment: I have one further inquiry, @mathlove.  How are you sure that $3 \nmid \sigma(p^{2a})$?  Sure, I understand that $p \neq 3$, and that $\gcd(p^{2a},\sigma(p^{2a}))=1$.  But how do you ensure that $3 \nmid \sigma(p^{2a})$?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : I've added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I fully understand. =)

Answer (score 1):

All else being equal, a larger count of divisors will result in a larger sum of divisors, and a larger sum of divisors will result in a larger gcd.  The count of divisors will the the product of one more than the powers of each distinct prime. I.e. if $n=\Pi p^{e_i}$, then the count of divisors of $n$ will be $\Pi (e_i+1)$. So to give yourself the best chance of having gcd >$\sqrt n$, you should have the exponents of primes as high as possible while keeping $n$ as small as possible. This then suggest using small primes, as that will result in larger powers with smaller resulting $n$. And the smallest odd prime number is 3. If you drop the odd requirement, your list would probably be dominated by powers of 2. And notice that more than half of your numbers are divisible by 5, the next smallest odd prime.

Comment: While I agree with your *heuristic* to a certain extent @Acccumulation, that is not a proof at all, is it not?  Perhaps someone with greater knowledge on analytic number theory could shed some insight on this one.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris A heuristic-type analysis seemed to be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

**Claim** : There is an odd integer $n$ such that
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n))\gt\sqrt n,\qquad 3^2\mid n,\qquad 3^3\not\mid n\qquad\text{and}\qquad 13\not\mid n$$

*Proof* :

For $n=3^2\times 5^4\times 11\times 71$, we get
$$\sigma(n)=13\times 781\times 12\times 72=2^5\times 3^3\times 11\times 13\times 71$$from which we have
$$\begin{align}\gcd(n,\sigma(n))&
=\gcd(3^2\times 5^4\times 11\times 71,2^5\times 3^3\times 11\times 13\times 71)
\\\\&=\gcd(3^2\times 11\times 71,3^3\times 11\times 71)
\\\\&=3^2\times 11\times 71\end{align}$$

It follows that
$$\begin{align}(\gcd(n,\sigma(n)))^2-n&=3^4\times 11^2\times 71^2-3^2\times 5^4\times 11\times 71
\\\\&=3^2\times 11\times 71\times (3^2\times 11\times 71-5^4)
\\\\&=3^2\times 11\times 71\times 6404
\\\\&\gt 0\qquad\square\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

(Not a complete answer.)

Note that, for $p$ prime and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$\gcd(p^k,\sigma(p^k))=1 \not\gt \sqrt{p^k},$$
so that $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$ implies $n$ is composite.

Perhaps the correct way to phrase the question is as follows:

> <s>If $n$ is an odd composite number satisfying $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$, does it follow that $3 \mid n$?</s>  <s>Under what suitable conditions does it follow that $3 \mid n$, if $n$ is an odd composite number satisfying $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$?</s> Under what suitable conditions does it follow that $3 \mid n$, if $n$ is an odd number satisfying $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: But you've already shown in the question that $\gcd(775,\sigma(775))\gt \sqrt{775}$ with $3\not\mid 775$, haven't you?

Comment: @mathlove, yes I did.  I apologize, I meant to add:  "Under what suitable conditions does it follow that $3 \mid n$, if $n$ is an odd composite number satisfying $\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) > \sqrt{n}$?"  Editing my answer in a while to reflect this change.  Thanks!